# getJSON vs. optJSON

Tags: json, getjson

I was looking over the [documentation](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) for `JSONObject` when I noticed the two methods: `getJSONObject(String key)` and `optJSONObject(String key)`. From the documentation, I figured they did nearly the same thing with one difference: If the key or value isn't found, then `getJSONObject()` throws a `JSONException` whereas `optJSONObject()` simply returns `null`.

1. Are there any other differences between `getJSONObject()` and `optJSONObject()`?
2. What are the advantages of `get` over `opt` and vice-versa?
3. Are there specific situations where I would want to use one over the other or where the use of one is strongly discouraged/prohibited?

Comment: As per questions 2 & 3, the best answer would probably be how you want to handle errors based on the context of your code.

Answer (score 15):

A value in the JSON may be optional, so using optJSONObject is better because you just have to check if it is null or not and continue your function.

Comment: I think if you are using `getJSONObject`, as it will throw the Exception, you can handle the wrong JSON format easier in `catch` if you use `try catch`

Answer (score 10):

`optString` returns the empty string ("") if the key you specify doesn't exist. `getString` throws a `JSONException`.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. `getJSONObject()` throws an exception when that object is not found. `optJSONObject()` returns null.
2. Honestly there aren't really any advantages to one over the other, it's really a matter of personal preference.
3. Only reason I can think of is for readability potentionally. For instance see how this code accomplishes the same thing

This option is a bit easier to read if you are doing a lot more when the object isn't present.

```
JSONObject object = jsonResponse.optJSONObject("object");

if(object == null)
{
    // handle not existing here
}
```

This option is a bit easier if you are only throwing another exception or doing something else that's one line.

```
JSONObject object = null;    

try
{
    object = jsonResponse.getJSONObject("object");
}
catch(JSONException je)
{
    // handle object not found here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using optJSONObject to my json file with key "sentences" and it return null but the correct result might JSONArray or String.

```
{
"sentences":[
  {
     "trans":"làm",
     "orig":"do",
     "translit":"",
     "src_translit":""
  }
]
}
```